# Trigger next pipeline stage when there is a pull request completed for assigned branch

Tags: azure, yaml, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-delivery

My YAML pipeline has 3 deployment stages:

```
Alpha servers -> Beta servers -> Production servers
```

I have 3 branches. One for alpha code, one for beta, and one for production. What I want to achieve is to automate the following workflow in YAML(I've already set a trigger for the alpha branch, but it's a question about later stages):

```
Changes merged to the alpha branch after a pull request is completed -> alpha branch code build -> deployment to alpha servers -> *manual testing performed on alpha servers* -> only these specific changes merged from alpha to beta branch -> beta branch code build -> deployment to beta servers -> *manual testing performed on beta servers* -> only these specific changes merged from beta to main branch -> main branch code build -> deployment to production servers
```

I can't figure out how to make beta and production stages run when changes are merged to the beta and main branches. If I declare triggers for all 3 branches (alpha, beta, main) it will create a new pipeline run every time so instead of having 1 run with specific changes:

```
alpha(run after merge to alpha branch) -> beta(run after merge to beta branch) -> prod(run after merge to main branch)
```

I'm using conditions for alpha, beta, prod deployments to check which branch has been merged to but I end up with 3 runs:

```
alpha(run after merge to alpha branch) -> beta(did not run) -> prod(did not run)
alpha(did not run) -> beta(run after merge to beta branch) -> prod(did not run)
alpha(did not run) -> beta(did not run) -> prod(run after merge to main branch)
```

My pipeline:

```
variables:
    - name: app_name
      value: 'myapp'

trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - alpha
    - beta

stages:
  - stage: buildAlpha
    condition: and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/alpha'))
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-2022

    jobs:
      - job: compile

        steps:
        - checkout: git://MyTeam/MyProjectTest@alpha

        - task: UseDotNet@2
          displayName: 'Use .NET Core 3.1'
          inputs:
            packageType: 'sdk'
            version: '3.1.x'

        - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
          displayName: 'Use NuGet 6.0.0'
          inputs:
            versionSpec: 6.0.0

        - task: NuGetCommand@2
          displayName: 'NuGet restore'
          inputs:
            restoreSolution: 'MyProject\MyProject.sln'

        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          inputs:
            command: 'publish'
            publishWebProjects: false
            projects: 'MyProject\MyProject.sln'
            arguments: '-o $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
            modifyOutputPath: false
            zipAfterPublish: true
        
        - publish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
          artifact: drop
        
  - stage: deployDev
    condition: and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/alpha'))
    jobs:
      - deployment: deployToAlpha
        variables:
          - group: DevVariables
        environment: 
          name: dev
          resourceType: VirtualMachine
          tags: web
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
                  displayName: 'IIS Web App Deploy'
                  inputs:
                    WebSiteName: 'myapp.og.com'
                    VirtualApplication: $(app_name)
                    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
                    TakeAppOfflineFlag: True
                    XmlVariableSubstitution: True
                    Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/**/*.zip'
                
                - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@4
                  displayName: 'Replace tokens in **/appsettings.json'
                  inputs:
                    targetFiles: 'F:/Websites/myapp.og.com/$(app_name)/appsettings.json'
                    actionOnMissing: fail
                    keepToken: true
                    actionOnNoFiles: fail
                    enableTelemetry: false  

  - stage: buildBeta
    condition: and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/beta'))
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-2022

    jobs:
      - job: compile

        steps:
        - checkout: git://MyTeam/MyProjectTest@beta

        - task: UseDotNet@2
          displayName: 'Use .NET Core 3.1'
          inputs:
            packageType: 'sdk'
            version: '3.1.x'

        - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
          displayName: 'Use NuGet 6.0.0'
          inputs:
            versionSpec: 6.0.0

        - task: NuGetCommand@2
          displayName: 'NuGet restore'
          inputs:
            restoreSolution: 'MyProject\MyProject.sln'

        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          inputs:
            command: 'publish'
            publishWebProjects: false
            projects: 'MyProject\MyProject.sln'
            arguments: '-o $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
            modifyOutputPath: false
            zipAfterPublish: true
        
        - publish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
          artifact: drop
  
  - stage: deployBeta
    condition: and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/beta'))
    jobs:
      - deployment: deployToBeta
        variables:
          - group: betavariables
        environment: 
          name: beta
          resourceType: VirtualMachine
          tags: web
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
                  displayName: 'IIS Web App Deploy'
                  inputs:
                    WebSiteName: 'myapp.og.com'
                    VirtualApplication: $(app_name)
                    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
                    TakeAppOfflineFlag: True
                    XmlVariableSubstitution: True
                    Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/**/*.zip'
                
                - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@4
                  displayName: 'Replace tokens in **/appsettings.json'
                  inputs:
                    targetFiles: 'F:/Websites/myapp.og.com/$(app_name)/appsettings.json'
                    actionOnMissing: fail
                    keepToken: true
                    actionOnNoFiles: fail
                    enableTelemetry: false
```

Comment: Please share your pipeline.

Comment: @DanielMann added the yaml file

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, Pull Request merges in three branches trigger three pipeline runs. This is an expected behavior.

In Yaml Pipeline, the trigger can only be set at the root level. It works on the entire pipeline. So three PR merges will trigger three pipeline runs, and they are independent。

When PR merge triggers the pipeline, it will run the matching stage based on the condition.

Variables will be evaluated with the same value, so some stages will run and others will skip.

For your requirement: three PR merges trigger different stages of the same pipeline run , I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can meet your requirement.

For a workaround, you can split into three pipelines according to the stages and set the corresponding trigger for each pipeline.

I suggest that you can create [a suggestion feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion)  to report the  feature requirement.